# Accessibility of Session variable in Jinja2 with different name

Tags: python, session, flask, jinja2

I want to show different header for person with logged in and person who logged out in Flask. Could I use the session variable directly in the jija2 template.

I have used different name for session since , another session variable name used for sqlalchamy session.

```
from flask import session as usersession
```

I have tried accessing the usersession variable but it's saying undefined. but when I use the  `session['username']` I could access the session variable.

further when I pop from usersession It's not popping from the session. Still session accessed in the tamplete has the `username` variable

```
usersession.pop('email', None)
usersession.pop('type', None)


jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'usersession' is undefined
```

My code is below .

```
{% if usersession['username'] is not  none %}
     {% include "store/headers/loginheader.html" %}
{% else %}
     {% include "store/headers/logoutheader.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views function, try `usersession[‘username’] = ‘username`

And in the template:

```
{{ usersession[‘username’] }}
```

For [sessions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm) make sure you have set up the environment correctly to be able to access sessions (ie a secret key).

Also have a look at [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as their ‘current_user’ object has great functionality and may be what you’re looking for